# Save text in a variable and display it when I click a button in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am started with the python code. I am trying to make a little code using Tkinter.

I have a window, where I ask the name.
Then when I click the "enter" button, I would like that the name appears in another window..

here is my code where I am stuck :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#.*. coding: utf-8 .*.

from Tkinter import *

fenetre = Tk()

info = Label(fenetre,text="entrez votre nom")
info.pack()

name = StringVar()
ligne_text = Entry(fenetre,textvariable = name,width=30)
ligne_text.pack()


display_button = Button(fenetre,text="Enter")
display_button.pack()


fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: where in that code are you stuck? It doesn't appear you've attached any code to the button. I suggest you read some documentation on how the Button object can be attached to a function.

Comment: I don't know how to save the text i entered in "name" and then display it when I press "Enter". I checked in internet and I don't find what I need.. Thank you @BryanOakley

Comment: Find some tutorial. This is not tutorial but can be usefull: effbot.org: [Button](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can set onpressed callback functions to buttons:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#.*. coding: utf-8 .*.

from Tkinter import *

fenetre = Tk()

info = Label(fenetre,text="entrez votre nom")
info.pack()

name = StringVar()
ligne_text = Entry(fenetre,textvariable = name,width=30)
ligne_text.pack()

def onPress():
    NewWindow = Toplevel()
    Label(NewWindow,textvariable=name).pack()

display_button = Button(fenetre,text="Enter",command=onPress)
display_button.pack()


fenetre.mainloop()
```